# BackgroundWorker cross-thread error ListView argument

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview

Why do I get at "ListViewItem lviFile = lvFiles.Items[i];" a cross-thread error, even if I use DoWorkEventArgs e for the ListView argument?

```
private void btUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bwUpload.RunWorkerAsync(lvFiles);
}

private void bwUpload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lvFiles = (ListView)e.Argument;

    for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lviFile = lviFile.Items[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're accessing it from a separate thread, you will need to use `Invoke` in order to use it.

```
private void btUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bwUpload.RunWorkerAsync(lvFiles);
}

private void bwUpload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lvFiles = (ListView)e.Argument;

    for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            ListViewItem lviFile = lviFile.Items[i];
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to write all inside the Invoke(), or how can i access the ListViewItem outside the Invoke()? It seems complicated for debuging, if I write all inside of the Invoke()...

Comment: You can't access it outside of the invoke, that's why it's there...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a control. you have to invoke the task in the thread the control is created in.

More info [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` to update the UI with the changes from  the `DoWork()` method.
Calling `ReportProgress()` on the `BackgroundWorker` allows you to pass an `object` as the second argument which you can then use in the `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: I dont want to update my ListView while DoWork(). I need the values from the ListViewItem...

Comment: But you are accessing `lvFiles` on a different thread which is causing you problems. `ProgressChanged` is where you can access these values without the exception.